# Getting user´s info with Apple Sign In

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Apple Signin to my Flutter app.

I have used the FlutterFire proposed code for it.

```
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
    // To prevent replay attacks with the credential returned from Apple, we
    // include a nonce in the credential request. When signing in with
    // Firebase, the nonce in the id token returned by Apple, is expected to
    // match the sha256 hash of `rawNonce`.
    final rawNonce = generateNonce();
    final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

    // Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
    final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      nonce: nonce,
    );

    // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
      rawNonce: rawNonce,
    );

    // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
    // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
 


    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
  }
```

Is there a way to get some of the user´s data, like email, name, profile image?

I would like to create a user account for my project using some of the apple user data.

When launching `signInWithApple()` I am getting the following dialog

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `getAppleIDCredential` and `signInWithCredential` are completed, and the user allowed to access the data you requested, these should be accessible from `appleCredential`. For example after this code is completed:

```
final rawNonce = generateNonce();
final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);
final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
  scopes: [
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
  ],
  nonce: nonce,
);

final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
  idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
  rawNonce: rawNonce,
);

final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
```

You can get user data from `appleCredential`:

```
appleCredential.familyName
appleCredential.givenName
appleCredential.email
```

It is good idea to wrap this whole sign in logic into a `try / catch` block to be able to catch exceptions.

Comment: My appleCredential familyName
and givenName are null